# String is empty in BackgroundWorker?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, backgroundworker

```
private void btntest_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var bgw = new BackgroundWorker();
    string reponse = string.Empty;
    bgw.DoWork += async (s,v) =>
    {
        reponse = await sendData();

    };
    bgw.RunWorkerCompleted += (s,v) =>
    {
        MessageBox.Show(reponse);
    };
    bgw.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

I don't know why message show response is empty? `await sendData()` mehthod is always returning string not empty?

Comment: what is your sendData method? also, can you try without the async/await and check if the result is always empty as well?

Comment: When I run this code in a normal c# app it works. Are you sure `sendData` returns any data?

Comment: sendData method is method post data to server ?

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
string reponse =string.Empty;

private void btntest_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    { 
      var bgw = new BackgroundWorker();
      bgw.DoWork += bw_DoWork;
      bgw.RunWorkerCompleted += backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted;
      bgw.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
 void async bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
              reponse = await sendData();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }

 void backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
           MessageBox.Show(reponse);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

`DoWork` cannot be `async`. Use `Task.Run` instead of `BackgroundWorker`:

```
private async void btntest_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  string response = await Task.Run(() => sendData());
  MessageBox.Show(reponse);
}
```

I have a series of posts on my blog describing how [`Task.Run` is superior to `BackgroundWorker` in every way](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/09/taskrun-vs-backgroundworker-conclusion.html).